# Domain Access Source - Canonical

Tags: 8, domain-access

for now domain access and source set the correct canonical domain and show the links linked to the correct page.

I can disable that and the links stay within the domain I’m currently on. Visitors won’t get redirected to a “new” page.

I’ve got two domains. Site A and site B. 
A has content from B but visitors from A should particularly know that there is site B except they land on B by Google search or wise versa. But there is content from B that has to appear on A. Without the penalty of double content, which it is right now.

How can I leave the links alone but set the canonical to the real source? D7 had that ability with tokens, D8 doesn’t because “it’s working as intended”

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done with Tokens. Not so elegant, but it works.